# How to set http-request node not to use environment set proxy settings?

Tags: node-red

The Node-RED I am working on is installed on top of an Ubuntu container.
(I didn't create this container nor can I modify it.)

I want to create a flow with a simple HTTP get request to another container on the same docker network but I keep on getting a 403 forbidden error.

```
[{"id":"332622ed.d87fbe","type":"http request","z":"8431aef4.eba67","name":"","method":"GET","ret":"txt","url":"http://172.16.0.5:8080/path/to/something","tls":"","x":890,"y":700,"wires":[["f49e6445.15d988"]]},{"id":"277f03cb.536f8c","type":"inject","z":"8431aef4.eba67","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"str","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":730,"y":700,"wires":[["332622ed.d87fbe"]]},{"id":"f49e6445.15d988","type":"debug","z":"8431aef4.eba67","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","x":1050,"y":700,"wires":[]}]
```

So I tried doing the request from within the docker container itself
i.e. through:

```
docker exec -it ubuntu_nodered bash
curl –X GET "http://172.16.0.5:8080/path/to/something"
```

The 403 forbidden error persists. Later, I found out the container has a proxy setting so I tried:

```
curl –X GET --noproxy "*" "http://172.16.0.5:8080/path/to/something"
```

Alas, I got a proper response from this command.

Now that I'm sure the issue is with the proxy... **How do I make the HTTP requests from the flow NOT TO USE the proxy settings from the environment it is in for requests on 172.16.0.x?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `NO_PROXY` environment variable. The doc for the variable can be found [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Proxies.html).

This should hold a comma separated list of hosts/ip addresses that should not be used with the proxy. Looking at this [question/answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23452/44275) it looks like you can not easily add ranges of IP addresses so you will need to add all the addresses in the range you want not to proxy.

Comment: Thank you for always answering my questions, sir hardillb. I've tried adding a `NO_PROXY="172.16.0.5"` line in the /etc/environment file and then stop-started the ubuntu_nodered container. But I still get 403 error when executing the flow.

Comment: That won't work, the change will not be persisted across a container restart.

Comment: Read the Docker documentation about how to pass in environment variables when the container is started

Comment: Oh, that's right. I totally forgot this. I will try to add `ENV NO_PROXY="172.16.0.5"` on the dockerfile and rebuild the image.